# Can you plot decimal values on an axis, but have the label show the hexadecimal equivalent in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data in a csv file with two columns: clock cycles in a microprocessor (displayed in decimal), and a 32-bit register 0 to 4000 (also displayed in decimal).

Everything works perfectly however I would like to be able to show the x-axis values in hexadecimal instead of decimal, as this makes much more sense to analyse. Is this possible? Currently I have to convert to hexadecimal every time I need to check some sequence of the data. I would also like to be able to hover over a data point and have the hexadecimal value display instead of the decimal value.

I have tried to plot the values as hex strings but they don't plot in order so it looks completely different and impossible to analyse without zooming in.

My code and graph is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

columns = ["a", "b"]

df = pd.read_csv("my_file_location.csv", usecols=columns, nrows=5000)

print("Contents in csv file:", df)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.00, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

plt.title('Reg / Clock Cycles)')
plt.xlabel('Clock Cycles', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Reg Value (Decimal)', fontsize=10)
plt.scatter(df.a, df.b) 
plt.show()
```

[image: Example graph]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hexadecimal X-axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189806/hexadecimal-x-axis-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @mkrieger1 This is closer to what I need, but it you cannot hover over a point and have it show the actual hex value. The x value remains blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can do this, although you will need to install a library called [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). This is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

x = np.random.randint(low=1, high=5000, size=100)
y = np.random.randint(low=10, high=4000, size=100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: hex(int(x)) + ", " + str(int(x)))

# Or try 
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: hex(int(x)))

mplcursors.cursor() 

plt.show()
```

With the help of [Tick formatters](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/tick-formatters.html#tick-formatters), you can format the ticks to any value you want, `mplcursors` just adds an annotation.

[image: Picture using hexadecimal on x axis]